# UE4 ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development error when building engine source

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4

After I've used a github UE4 version for a while now, I noticed that I wasn't able to build the engine again without having this error complaining about ShaderCompileWorker. Is there anyway to solve this?
Here is the error message after building the engine in Visual Studio 2019:
[image]

Comment: Could  you please provide the github link about the UE4 engine?

Comment: Besides, I think you should [follow the guidance from github link](https://github.com/Jggggg/SourceCode/tree/bbaf87ffde315e546d4c86120a1dfe5b98926a3c#getting-up-and-running).

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Here is the linkhttps://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/tree/4.24  NB: I have followed all the instructions, that's why it used to work, I'm not sure why it currently doesn't build correctly

Comment: 1) try to run `GenerateProjectFiles.bat -2017` in CMD to regenerate the sln for VS2017. 2) Then, run VS2017 as Administrator, after that, build `UE4` project first.